# What version of Typescript does IntelliJ v13 support?

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I need to use generics in Typescript, which were added in v0.9 ([after IntelliJ IDEA 12.1 according to this](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5494761#5494761)). Does anyone know if IntelliJ 13 has support for Typescript 0.9?

Comment: Support them in what way? It's just a simple editor that understands the basic language syntax and calls the compiler a lot to validate code.

Comment: Support Typescript generics in a way that does not pollute the editor with red error markers telling me that my code is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment : http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP however the support is available in Webstorm 7

Comment: I did see that page, but I wasn't able to find anything about support for a specific Typescript versions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 0.9 is supported in IDEA 13. I work on a project, where I've used generics and AMD loading, both of which did not work with IDEA 12.

I'm using InteliJ IDEA 13 and it works fine so far in, but the support of TS is still choppy in some edge cases.